# Prolems with mxl 770

Tags: microphone, audio-recording, recording, daw, home-studio

I'm a voice actor and I'm trying to record a few tidbits. Now I'm just doing this in my apartment, but it's pretty quiet in here and all of my fans and such are off. When I plug up headphones directly into my mixer (a xenyx 802)it sounds clear and fine. How ever when ever I record something (connecting my sound board through my Desktop pc) it comes out sounding like there's air rushing past the microphone. I'm not sure if that describes it right. does this sound like a common thing? the only sound in the room (as far as I can tell) is my desktop but it isn't THAT loud.

[Test file for mxl 770](http://www.filedropper.com/mxl770test)

Comment: Could you post an example? It can be hard to tell for sure but the characteristic sound might clue someone in as to what's happening.

Comment: I added a file too my post of me testing the microphone, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What's happening to the signal between the output of the Xenyx 802 and your recording software? Sometimes cheap soundcards do a bad job at converting analog to digital, so you end up with a lot of noise, like what i heard in your recording.

If you can, try recording through the Xenyx into a different analog to digital system. Maybe you or a friend have an MBox or Zoom/Tascam/etc. recorder? Those systems are pretty solid in terms of AD (Analogue to Digital) conversion, so that will tell you whether the problem is your soundcard or not. If it is your soundcard, look into some better quality options.

It's a chain: Voice > Room+Mic Positioning > Mic > Preamp > AD Conversion. So you need to be able to isolate and test each stage (although in your case you can skip the first 2) in order to find the weak link.

Good luck!